# The requested URL /get.php was not found on this server

Tags: wordpress, 404

I am having problems with my Wordpress and I don't know why. I haven't modified anything and suddenly, I see this error:

[image: Error]

What should I do?

Comment: Sorry but your question is too board and unclear because of the lack of information.

Comment: You should probably ask this on http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT:** My bad, there is a get.php in the Akismet plugin that comes with WP. Is that plugin enabled but messed up?

You should def provide more detailed information such as how you are producing this error, where its happening, WP version, how long its been installed, any plugins you use, information about server/host, etc. This risks being locked for too broad otherwise.

Anyways, there is no get.php in [recent] Wordpress installations. So you would have have to have modified it somehow otherwise it wouldnt be looking for a file that didnt come with itself. I would run a security audit on your server to make sure that get.php is not a drop. First place to look is htaccess, then in your FTP logs, then everywhere else. [You can use this mod to attempt to audit the WP filebase, but no guarantees](http://www.wordfence.com/).

Comment: I have run WordFence and finally I detect that my site was hacked somehow. It is the second time they installed me one of this hacks. It is a PHP backdoor. I think it has to be with the Theme. I am using Newspaper Theme from Themeforest. What should I do next? Restore my files from yesterday backup?

Comment: @alexgarciab Not everyone realizes that a theme can be vulnerable- they are thinking of updating WP and sometimes look at plugins, but almost never pay attention to themes which can be more vulnerable at times. Make sure your code- all of your code, WP, plugins, and themes are up to date and *not* vulnerable before getting too carried away. Or you will be hacked again.

Comment: @alexgarciab you have been hacked twice? I would backup then wipe the server and start from scratch, or move hosts. Then reinstall clean using better security. Yeah the theme is an open door too... Careful with those. Keep an eye on htaccess too

Comment: Finally I installed WordFence plugin and it seems that it is protecting my site. They tried to brute-force recover my Wordpress Password and the plugin blocked that IP.